# Upload File Size Limit ? - Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

On trying to upload a .mp4 file(40mB-20minutes) on a 12month free-trial account in Google Cloud Storage ,the upload stops before completion(~1%). 
However ,it does accept shorter .mp4 files (2mB-12seconds).

**Is there a upload filesize limit during the 12month free trial ?**

I am currently located in the Asia region and have selected the Asia(multiple regions in Asia)option storage bucket .

[Upload Stopped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0Wh9.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There's a max size limit of 5T: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert

There's no smaller limit for free trial users.